# Behaviour discrepancy with Docker container

Tags: java, docker

I am developing a small Java app that is supposed to check an email inbox. When I deploy it in my production environment and execute the jar, the connection to the inbox is well established using the port 110.

**Issue:**

I put the jar within its own Docker container, the port 995 (secured connection) is used instead, failing the connection. The port used is defined in a properties file included in the jar, and there is no mention anywhere in my project of the port 995.

Is there a Docker setting forcing this behaviour?

Here is the Dockerfile used:

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN mkdir /webapps
COPY ./mailer_skeleton-1.0.0.jar /webapps/
CMD ["java",  "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "-jar", "/webapps/mailer_skeleton-1.0.0.jar"]
```

Here is the result from the command docker inspect mailer:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "ceb08f179073aebd8ce4d9731b5c038d4350c064d7367f553ab264dcb632b68b",
        "Created": "2020-08-06T07:31:55.607821298Z",
        "Path": "java",
        "Args": [
            "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod",
            "-jar",
            "/webapps/mailer-1.0.0.jar"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 32587,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-08-06T07:31:56.691286841Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:10ee3c91bcdac8c6194333acc882237bb2a1d06d82143aa024db1ecb8ac1012c",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/data/docker/containers/ceb08f179073aebd8ce4d9731b5c038d4350c064d7367f553ab264dcb632b68b/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/data/docker/containers/ceb08f179073aebd8ce4d9731b5c038d4350c064d7367f553ab264dcb632b68b/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/data/docker/containers/ceb08f179073aebd8ce4d9731b5c038d4350c064d7367f553ab264dcb632b68b/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/data/docker/containers/ceb08f179073aebd8ce4d9731b5c038d4350c064d7367f553ab264dcb632b68b/ceb08f179073aebd8ce4d9731b5c038d4350c064d7367f553ab264dcb632b68b-json.log",
        "Name": "/mailer",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/user4docker/ftthapp/mailer/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "ftthapp_mynet",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8086"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/data/docker/overlay2/f2c43a10d3bcab1f5f190cab08cd201c7b4315c49c7c2c1ba78199c3946b381c-init/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/130f81d108823cb65aeb2d4370a8c71ffe0db40f088f26c16f987cc712b7238d/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/8220484c973a572a6a9c83ae1a16a5b34b448049c9fa96419ca56ca97959b830/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/a1b62ad1d3a6c1b3c5e186a4fdf406ab0dcd578c8476fa4b65ce008cf99bd73d/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/d33136d2b5652169a6f7ab76a4209be375ddf4f5fd4b12839a157b269ec9ea04/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/bd450a561912c6043a3c733af0ba5e2ac458cb3c2af0ff0a93f7eceac9828680/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/ecc604daa8220c0096d4650779fdac9416ea26b0c2ec3de4ad4dd1d23f4142c2/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/fd67ed0df8ee68254f9f03055ea856048bfd8afa3ec0c35bb7c515f35d3f3a01/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/67e424b4b991719e57482046423b940bdc7f16a658d134afded276e2303fb10b/diff:/data/docker/overlay2/1e287fd7962f340b71a37c6b5bf6b5715c42de0efa9cb6f2a203a948327ba85f/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/data/docker/overlay2/f2c43a10d3bcab1f5f190cab08cd201c7b4315c49c7c2c1ba78199c3946b381c/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/data/docker/overlay2/f2c43a10d3bcab1f5f190cab08cd201c7b4315c49c7c2c1ba78199c3946b381c/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/data/docker/overlay2/f2c43a10d3bcab1f5f190cab08cd201c7b4315c49c7c2c1ba78199c3946b381c/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/user4docker/ftthapp/mailer/webapps",
                "Destination": "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "ceb08f179073",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "https_proxy=https://198.18.37.248:3128",
                "http_proxy=http://198.18.37.248:3128",
                "HTTPS_PROXY=https://198.18.37.248:3128",
                "HTTP_PROXY=http://198.18.37.248:3128",
                "HTTPS_PROXY=https://198.18.37.248:3128",
                "http_proxy=http://198.18.37.248:3128",
                "https_proxy=https://198.18.37.248:3128",
                "HTTP_PROXY=http://198.18.37.248:3128",
                "PATH=/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-8",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u265"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "java",
                "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod",
                "-jar",
                "/webapps/mailer-1.0.0.jar"
            ],
            "Image": "mailer",
            "Volumes": {
                "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "5a6def467414d7328f02df00df1cc0299b83807ae08e23a344acfa6e89963f8a",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "ftthapp",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/home/user4docker/ftthapp",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "mailer",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.1"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "b7446cbc478db125e37a90865da6ca44e226bd9f836c1fa07e6deb0d2fa8c36e",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8086"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/b7446cbc478d",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "ftthapp_mynet": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "mailer",
                        "ceb08f179073"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "a6c0bdf4b9de5df2990dfb19357e3bdcb8332676f1411937b57afdb828e7cbe9",
                    "EndpointID": "dae31f543f29fa3c30f04bc88f954df90107093eb69ebbc08e42274835599388",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.16.1",
                    "IPAddress": "192.168.16.12",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:0c",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Add the dockerfile and a docker instect please

Comment: The properties file you mention is _in_ the jar or you should have copied it into the container?

Comment: The properties file is indeed in the jar, included at compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the new jar was not propertly used in the container. I had to force-recreate the build to take into account the new version.